# Get y position after columntext go

Tags: itext

with a columnText object inside a contentByte (5.4.1)

If I do

```
go = ct.go(true)
yy = ct.getYLine()
```

I can get the value of the last written y position into the variable yy but the Paragraph inside the column Text is not written (obviously)

If I do

```
go = ct.go()
yy = ct.getYLine()
```

then nothing is returned to yy.
how do I get the ct written AND get the YLine value back too???

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce this problem. This is my code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;


public class ColumnTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("columntest.pdf"));
        document.open();
        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
        ct.setSimpleColumn(PageSize.A4);
        ct.addElement(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
        ct.addElement(new Paragraph("Hello Sun"));
        ct.addElement(new Paragraph("Hello Moon"));
        ct.go();
        System.out.println(ct.getYLine());
        document.close();
    }
}
```

This is what is written to the System.out:

```
788.0
```

That's the same result as when I replace `ct.go();` by `ct.go(true);` (but when I work in simulation mode, I get an exception saying *"The document has no pages"* for obvious reasons).

Comment: Thanks Bruno I seemed to fix what I needed with cb.endText() followed by cb.beginText() - not sure why it works but it did...